# Soundcloud API get tracks by multiple users in one go

Tags: soundcloud

I understand that by using the code below i get all tracks by user XXXXX

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/XXXXX/tracks.json?client_id=MY ID
```

Now my question is how can i get all tracks by two or more different users in one go. For Example user YYYY and XXXX

The code below does not work

```
 http://api.soundcloud.com/users/XXXXX/YYYYY/tracks.json?client_id=MY ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do it through the API.  You have to make two or more requests to get each users tracks and then combine them into one collection.  Let me know if you need any additional information.